# Python xml.dom.minidom.parse() function ignores DTDs

Tags: python, xml

I have the following Python code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml.parsers.expat

try:
    domTree = ml.dom.minidom.parse(myXMLFileName)
except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError, e:
    return e.args[0]
```

which I am using to parse an XML file. Although it quite happily spots simple XML errors like mismatched tags, it completely ignores the DTD specified at the top of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServerConfig SYSTEM "ServerConfig.dtd">
```

so it doesn't notice when mandatory elements are missing, for example. How can I switch on DTD checking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798/how-do-i-validate-xml-against-a-dtd-file-in-python) - the accepted answer is to use [lxml validation](http://codespeak.net/lxml/validation.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'd hoped to avoid having to work outside the standard library, but lxml certainly does the trick. A lot easier to read, too.

Answer (score 3):

Just by way of explanation: Python xml.dom.minidom and xml.sax use the expat parser by default, which is a non-validating parser.  It may read the DTD in order to do entity replacement, but it won't validate against the DTD.

[gimel](/users/6491/gimel) and [Tim](/users/20670/tim) recommend lxml, which is a nicely pythonic binding for the libxml2 and libxslt libraries.  It supports validation against a DTD.  I've been using lxml, and I like it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, this is what my code looks like now:

```
from lxml import etree

try:
    parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True)
    domTree = etree.parse(myXMLFileName, parser=parser)
except etree.XMLSyntaxError, e:
    return e.args[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend lxml over xmlproc because the PyXML package (containing xmlproc) is not being developed any more; the latest Python version that PyXML can be used with is 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to switch from expat to xmlproc.
See:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/220472/